# Error converting LINQ anonymous type to IList<>

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following LINQ join:

```
var query = _ABC.Table
            .Join(_DEF.Table, cef => ...etc... })
            .Join(_GHI.Table, extf => ...etc...})
            .Select(jcefn=> new { XYZ = jcefn....etc...});
```

The linq is good and returns what I expect (verified in LINQ pad).

I am the trying to pass the query into an extension method with this signature:

```
public PagedList(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{ ... }
```

So I thought this would be acceptable:

```
var FPaged = new PagedList<MyObject>(query.ToList(), pageIndex, pageSize);
```

But that apparently isn't making the compiler happy. It is saying:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable etc.

So obviously I need to change my linq anonymous type but not sure exactly what to change it to?

Note I did NOT include alot of code for brevity thinking it wasn't needed for understanding but I will gladly edit it in if needed.

Thank You

Comment: Don't call the ToList() on your query, The complaint is that it can't cast from IQueryable to List.

Comment: RIGHT?? Well that's what I did first and it told me:  cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyObj>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PagedList requires an `IQueryable<MyQuery>`. Your query object is of type `IQueryable<anonymous-type>`. To get an `IQueryable<MyQuery>` you need to change your select to:

```
var query = _ABC.Table
            .Join(_DEF.Table, cef => ...etc... })
            .Join(_GHI.Table, extf => ...etc...})
            .Select(jcefn=> new MyObject(){ XYZ = jcefn....etc...});
```

You do not need .ToList() to turn this into an IQueryable, it already is.

However, if you do want to execute and cache the IQueriable before passing it to the function, you could do

```
var cachedQuery = query.ToList();
var FPaged = new PagedList<MyObject>(cachedQuery.AsQueryAble<MyObject>(), pageIndex, pageSize);
```

In most cases this is not what you want. The PagedList requires an IQueryable most likely because it will only retrieve the part of the data that is currently needed for a particular page, leaving the rest of the potentially huge dataset behind the query in the database.

But if you actually want to retrieve all the data only once, and then later turn it into a PagedList, this is the way to go. You can then also reuse the cachedQuery in other places, without causing another database retrieval.

Comment: OHHHHH...Don't I feel dumb!! This is what I was missing. Select(jcefn=> new **MyObject()**{ XYZ = jcefn....etc...}); See I didn't realize that I could change it from anonymous to an object in the select. I though I had to do transforms after the select. I know probably a dumb noob thing to you guys. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 10):

Well yes - `query.ToList()` will return a `List<T>`, which doesn't implement `IQueryable<T>`. Indeed, the `ToList()` would render the paging less useful, as it would all be done *locally* after fetching the whole table into memory.

Just get rid of the call to `ToList()` and it may well be fine.

EDIT: Okay, if it's not fine because of the anonymous type, adding a `ToList` call isn't going to help. You either want to use a query which projects to an `IQueryable<MyObject>`, or if you really want a paged query for the anonymous type, you could add an extension method:

```
public static class PagingExtensions
{
    public static PagedList<T> Paginate<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
                                           int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        return new PagedList<T>(source, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
// TODO: Use a more sensible variable name
var FPaged = query.Paginate(pageIndex, pageSize);
```

Comment: RIGHT?? Well that's what I did first and it told me:  cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyObj>'

Comment: @user1278561 try `var FPaged = new PagedList(query.ToList(), pageIndex, pageSize);` You are specifying that PagedList is going to take a MyObject type, but it's an anonymous type.

Comment: That's because MyObject isn't the same as the anonymous type. Either select it over or make it a MyObject initially instead of an anonymous type. Otherwise it's like trying to insert a string into an int.

Comment: Sure...MyObj is not the same as anonymous type. But you lost me with select it over...do you mean project it as MyObj instead of anonymous?

Comment: That or use `.Select()` to transform the elements, which is a worse idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet You are correct. It didn't help and obviously my understanding is not complete but I am learning quite a bit from everyone contributions to this thread.

Comment: @user1278561: See my edit for a potential way forward.

Comment: @user1278561, yes, projecting it as MyObject is also a way to solve this. Depending on how MyObject is constructed this can be as simple as `.Select(jcefn=> new MyObject(){ XYZ = jcefn....etc...});`, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20638770/145999) for details. If you want to keep the query type anonymous for maximum flexibility, then Jon's extension method is the way to go

Answer (score 6):

Get rid of the ToList(). You need an IQueryable not an IList

```
var FPaged = new PagedList(query, pageIndex, pageSize);
```